# Standard Windows Forms reference .NET Core project

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is it possible to have a standard Windows Forms project and reference a project that is written in .NET Core?

This is the .NET Core project JSON:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {
    }
  }
}
```

I added the project as a reference but then nothing happens. I am trying to use Entity Framework 7 with Windows Forms.

Comment: Winforms and .NET Core **don't mix** ....

Comment: Your project.json is a .NET standard project, not solely .NET core. Since you're supporting .NET 4.6.1 it should work (given you're referencing the right assembly)